# NServiceBus - "Type was not registered in the serializer."

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

NServiceBus noob here. I've created a simple Winforms app that sends a message to my local queue. It works locally. I can see the test messages in my queue when I run it locally. No exceptions thrown.

But when I run the same sample app on a machine on a different AD domain, it throws the following exception.

[image]

Here's the code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private IBus bus;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bus = Configure.With()
            .UnityBuilder()
            .XmlSerializer()
            .MsmqTransport()
            .UnicastBus()
            .ImpersonateSender(true)
            .SendOnly();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            bus.Send("girish@my-pc-name.domain.net", new TestMessage() { OrderId = "99" });
            label1.Text = "Message sent successfully!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            label1.Text = ex.ToString();
            //throw;
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class TestMessage : IMessage
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
}
```

I even decided to pass an string array as the message and it says "System.String was not registered in the serializer...."

So I know it's not the TestMessage type that's the problem.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a firewall issue. Port 1801 was blocked. I had to work with the Infrastructure & Network Support team to figure this one out.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing would points towards the fact that NServiceBus cannot find the appropriate assembly. The assembly your message is in. Don't know what you're doing with the string, because you are using IMessage. Are you using NServiceBus 2.x?

Besides that, it's better specify the queue where you're sending to in your configuration, instead of in code. From [documentation](http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/852419-hosting-nservicebus-in-your-own-process)

```
<UnicastBusConfig>
  <MessageEndpointMappings>
    <add Messages="MessageDLL" Endpoint="DestinationQueue@TargetMachine"/>
  </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

I don't know what you're exactly doing, but aren't you sending from one AD domain to another domain? Is there a trust between the domains so you can send message from MSMQ on domain A to MSMQ on domain B?

Comment: The port 1801 was blocked. That was the reason. But as you can see, the error message was misleading which threw me off for a bit. Thanks for your help.